Why command queue:work work out only 1 row from jobs table?
In laravel 11 / livewire 3 / app using laravel/scout: ^10.11 for meilisearch
I use queues and after I import data into jobs table I have to run command queue:work
$ php artisan queue:work

   INFO  Processing jobs from the [default] queue.

  2024-10-15 09:37:46 Laravel\Scout\Jobs\MakeSearchable ............................................................................................................................................................................................................ RUNNING
  2024-10-15 09:37:46 Laravel\Scout\Jobs\MakeSearchable ...................................................................................................................................................................................................... 217.24ms DONE
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/CurrenciesXM$ php artisan queue:work

   INFO  Processing jobs from the [default] queue.

  2024-10-15 09:37:52 Laravel\Scout\Jobs\MakeSearchable ............................................................................................................................................................................................................ RUNNING
  2024-10-15 09:37:52 Laravel\Scout\Jobs\MakeSearchable

But having more 20 rows in jobs I have to run queue:work command more 20 rows - 1 time for any row import
Checking manuals at https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/scout I did not found any options to work all jobs in 1 command.
Are there some options for that ?
